# Running an animation one after the other fails

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to animate an image to rotate left and right when selected, basically to let the user which the object they're touching.

I found some code for animating:

```
- (void)rotateImage:(UIImageView *)image duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
              curve:(int)curve degrees:(CGFloat)degrees delay:(CGFloat)delay
{
    // Setup the animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:delay];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    // The transform matrix
    CGAffineTransform transform = 
    CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees));
    image.transform = transform;

    // Commit the changes
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

However, when I try to run two animations, only the last one ever works. Even with a proper delay, only the second animation will show:

```
[self rotateImage:self duration:.5 
                curve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn degrees:60 delay:0];
    [self rotateImage:self duration:.5 
                curve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn degrees:-60 delay:5];
```

What can I do to create the animation so it rotates left, then rotates right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
// animation left
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:10];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
       // animation right
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
       // done
    }];

    }];
```

found it here

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/

Comment: Close, but ignores the delay between animations and also ignores the easing.

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(60));
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:5.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
      animations:^{
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-60));
      }
      completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Animation blocks are definitely the way to go. This should replicate what you're trying to do,  including the easing. This assumes your calling from a view controller, but if your putting this code into a UIView or UIImageView, then just replace self.view with self.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(60));
} completion:^(BOOL finished){}];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:5.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-60));
} completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

Comment: For some reason the first animation doesn't occur if there second one is there. So same issue as before.

Comment: You can't run two animations like that, the second one will cancel the first since they are animating the same thing.  You need to put the second one INSIDE the first one's completion block.